# How do I use the rectangle node command in tikz for latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can someone explain what each part of this program does? What do the coordinates mean? What does the rectangle node mean? What does the `yshift` mean?

```
\usepackage{tikz}  
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle node[yshift=-1cm]{x} (2,1)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: One way to learn about Ti*k*Z is to try and change things, and see what happens. Another very effective way of learning is to read some digest about it, and after that, you may even read the [Ti*k*Z/PGF manual](https://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf) (you don't have toread everything but only pick what you need in it). Then try again. Have a nice trip in this wonderful land.

Comment: As it now stands, all those coordinates and shifts have no effect whatsoever.  The tikzpicture is positioned relative to the bounding box.  Try `\draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);` right before the end of the tikz;picture.

Answer (score 6):

The `tikz` package is used to create detailed graphics.  It's primary environment is the `tikzpicture` environment, in which commands for drawing the graphic are detailed.  In this `tikz` environment, individual commands are terminated with semicolons.

The `\draw` macro is for putting ink on the plot.  It can take many forms.  The form used here asks for a rectangle to be drawn, with sides parallel to the graph axes.

As to the command

```
\draw (0,0) rectangle node[yshift=-1cm]{x} (2,1);
```

two opposite corners of rectangle are given at (0,0) and (2,1). The node at which the label x is placed, normally in the center of the rectangle at (1,.5), is instead shifted down 1cm to (1,-.5), below the rectangle.

In the MWE, I add 4 nodes (0,0), (2,1), (1,.5) and (1,-.5) to give perspective.  I also show a different `\draw` command that merely connects two points specified (0,0) and (2,1).  Note that multiple points can be chained together in the command to draw a set of connected lines.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node at (0,0) {A};
\node at (2,1) {B};
\node at (1,.5) {C};
\node at(1,-.5) {D};
\draw (0,0) -- (2,1);
\draw (0,0) rectangle node[yshift=-1cm]{x} (2,1);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]